# Php regex for number with point after each three digits

Tags: php, regex

I want to make a number validation that checks if the user hasn't already added the points after each three digits. I plan to do this verification using refex

So for example 11.231.121.313 is a valid number, also 11231121313 but 11231.121.313 is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(\d+|\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})*)$
```

The first alternation allows you to have simply all digits.  The second checks for 1-3 digits optionally followed by groups of a decimal point with 1-3 following digits.  This works for your examples.

Comment: Yes, this works. I've tried about 5 regular expresions in the past 30 minutes but non worked. Thanks.

Comment: The final `\d` character class should be `\d{3}`, not `\d{1,3}`, as it currently accepts invalid input: [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4JAtuH)...

Comment: @ircmaxell that's fine; the requirements in the question were unclear to me.  I thought that `11.11.11.11` would also be valid.  If this is not the case, then as @ircmaxell says you can change the repetition requirement

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})+|\d+)$/', $number)) {
    // correct number
}
```

UPD: Add expression for only numbers